# Как нарисовать график функции?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Как нарисовать график функции `y=actg(bx+c)` относительно трех переменных в `VS`?

Comment: Visual Studio это IDE пожалуйста уточни язык

Comment: Вроде бы C++

Comment: нужно искать библиотеки для построения графиков на c++ либо посомтреть на эту http://www.dislin.de/

Comment: ZedGraph подходит?

Answer (score 3):

Вот [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread224340.html#post1260800) есть пример. Сам пример я вставил ниже. Остается лишь понять и сделать под определенную функцию.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x;
    HDC hDC = GetDC(GetConsoleWindow());
    HPEN Pen = CreatePen( PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    SelectObject( hDC, Pen );
    MoveToEx( hDC, 0, 85, NULL );
    LineTo( hDC, 200, 85 );
    MoveToEx( hDC, 100, 0, NULL );
    LineTo( hDC, 100, 170 );
    for (x = -8.0f; x <= 8.0f; x += 0.01f ) // O(100,85) - center
    {
        MoveToEx( hDC, 10*x+100, -10*sin(x)+85, NULL );//10 - scale
        LineTo( hDC, 10*x+100, -10*sin(x)+85 );
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```